# How to measure network throughput with IPerf3 and multiple socat proxies

Tags: iperf, socat

I have a particular device which acts as a "strange" TLS proxy and I want to measure the throughput of it with IPerf3.

The device under test is "Peter". It has an API to trigger connection to two TLS servers.
It will proxy their payload from one channel to another.

I can run on "Alice" IPerf and before it socat as a TLS proxy. And on "Bob" the TLS-server to TCP-server (strangest part) but it fails with "iperf3: error - unable to connect stream: Connection refused". If I use netcat instead of the iperf on the two ends, all works as expected.

I tried to test the setup without the "Peter" so to connect directly from Alice to Bob, but also no luck. Any ideas?

Here without Peter:

```bash
iperf3 -s -p 15001 --verbose -d
socat -v -v -d -d -b 131072 -g openssl-listen:8443,reuseaddr,fork,cert=server.crt,key=server.key,verify=0,ignoreeof       tcp-listen:16000,reuseaddr,ignoreeof
socat -v -v -d -d -b 131072 -g tcp4:127.0.0.1:15001,ignoreeof   openssl-connect:127.0.0.1:8443,cert=server.crt,key=server.key,verify=0,cafile=server.crt,ignoreeof
iperf3 -c 127.0.0.1 -4 -p 16000 --verbose -t 5 --forceflush -d -Z
```

Setup:

```
                                                                                                        
             Alice                               Peter                                Bob               
                                                                                                        
                                                                                                        
   IPerf  ┌──────────┐  TLS             TLS   ┌────────────┐  TLS            TLS  ┌───────────┐   IPerf 
   Server │          │ Server     2    Client │            │ Client    3    Server│           │   Client
          │          ├────────────────────────┤            ├──────────────────────┤           │         
          │          │                        │            │                      │           │         
          └──────────┘                        └────────────┘                      └───────────┘         
             socat                                   ▲                               socat              
           tcp <> tls-server                         │                            tls-server  tcp-server
                                                     │                                                  
                                                     │                                                  
                                                     │                                                  
                                                  1  │                                                  
                                                     │                                                  
                                                     │                                                  
                                                     │                                                  
                                                     │                                                  
                                                                                                        
                                              Command to connect                                        
                                              Alice and Bob via 2 TLS channels
```

Without Peter:

```
           Alice                                Bob                
                                                                   
                                                                   
 IPerf  ┌──────────┐  TLS              TLS  ┌───────────┐   IPerf  
 Server │          │ Client           Server│           │   Client 
        │          ├────────────────────────┤           │          
        │          │                        │           │          
        └──────────┘                        └───────────┘          
           socat                               socat               
         tcp <> tls-client                  tls-server  tcp-server
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do it like this. iPerf runs in server mode and on the other side the client mode.
Because it use it's own daemon and process it can't bind to another daemon or process.

You can only measure the network throughput of the whole server